# bounding box appearance - controls customization with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, overriding, fabricjs

I want to know is there a way to change the bounding box icon, I read source code in fabric.js, it generates square box for bounding box, but I want to change it to circle or change to my custom appearance. could you advise me?

Comment: i know this question is very old and probably out of your interest now, but please get a look and approve it so other users can benefit from this

Answer (score 9):

Fastest way to customize controls is to write your own `_drawControl` function and make it compatible with fabricjs standard to override it.
Remember that this function is called 9 times for every render, so try to stay low with code and drawings. Also if you modify the context ( ctx ) remember to use `.save` and `.restore` to do not mess up rendering pipeline.

FabricJs will call the function with `top` and `left` ready for a rectangle, so the corner will be at `top + size/2` and `left + size/2`, where size is `this.cornerSize`

```
function newControls(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
  if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
        return;
      }
      var size = this.cornerSize;
      isVML() || this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);
      ctx.arc(left + size/2, top + size/2, size/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
}

fabric.Object.prototype._drawControl = newControls;
```

```js
function newControls(control, ctx, methodName, left, top) {
  if (!this.isControlVisible(control)) {
        return;
      }
      var size = this.cornerSize;
      this.transparentCorners || ctx.clearRect(left, top, size, size);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(left + size/2, top + size/2, size/2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      ctx.stroke();
}

fabric.Object.prototype._drawControl = newControls;
fabric.Object.prototype.cornerSize = 15;
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');


canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({width:100, height:100, top:50, left:50}));
canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.getObjects()[0]);
```

```html
<script type ="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: I discovered an issue. Could be my implementation, but the rounded corners are inside a box, I guess the original corner. Is there a way to prevent that? sample: https://jsfiddle.net/hello_world/gxbhjyzg/7/ Thanks! Ideally will be just a circle (same color fill and border)

Comment: You should not clear the box ( clearRect ) beforw drawing. If you want white circles, do stroke AND fill. fill with white.

Answer (score 4):

Check these examples:

http://fabricjs.com/customization/

Example 2:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c3');
  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));

  canvas.item(0).set({
    borderColor: 'red',
    cornerColor: 'green',
    cornerSize: 6,
    transparentCorners: false
  });
  canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not answer to my question.

Comment: I need custom the 9 small box of bounding box, I want circle instead of small square

Comment: No, there is no built-in support for changing shape of object controls at the moment. You might be able to hack something on top.

Comment: maybe I need to overwrite bounding box when object:selected happens

Answer (score 1):

This works for the latest version of fabricjs (4.4 as of now).

You have an example online, http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization, that allows you to perform basic customization on the controls globally.

Its as simple as:

```
fabric.Object.prototype.borderColor = 'blue';
```

to change border color to blue for example.

Another demo, that is dependent on fabricjs 4, http://fabricjs.com/custom-control-render, has examples that allows you to add custom controls. Just leaving this here for anyone interested.